# How to get file's name in File watcher job in Autosys?

Tags: autosys, file-watcher

I am new to Autosys and have a query. I want to detect an arrival of a file. Hence I am using a file watcher job with watch_file as *. Now, I want to get the file name as I have to pass the name as a parameter to the next job. How can I get the filename? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real easy way to get the filename. A query on the wcc database and Table called dbo.MON_JOB there is a column AGENT_STATUS that will contain the filename.

You would need to filter based on the job name.

Hope that helps.
Dave